# Trying to integrate jest and react with amchart but getting an error . What could be the issue?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, amcharts4

Following is the error that I am getting while I run npm test:

```
      export { System, system } from "./.internal/core/System";
        ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
      3 | import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";


      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
```

Comment: have you installed `babel-jest` yet?

Comment: yes I have it installed

Comment: still, looks like it is not applied. show `package.json` content(just `jest` section).

Comment: "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns ": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ]
  }

Comment: for anyone who is not ejected, `transformIgnorePatterns` is not really an option :/

Comment: finnaly find a way to use it without ejecting, posted as an answer

Answer (score 3):

AmCharts supply their package in ES2015 standart, so it doesnt support IE9 or any old browser.

React default scripts enforces that all used libraries come compiled compatible with CommonJS.

By default Jest doesnt compile any of node_modules and attempts to run amCharts code as is and fails.

If you are ejected from react-scripts then you can update jest config:

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$"
    ],
...
}
```

If you dont want to eject you will need to use transformIgnorePatterns as cli option:

```
react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns '[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$'"
```

*Note:* One of the reasons why react team is agianst using this option is that, you code under test will be different from one in production (compiled vs not compiled), but as far as you dont test charts and just mock them as dependancy this should be fine.

Comment: added this under module.exports, and this also worked for amcharts 5

module.exports = {
  
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$',
  ] ...